# Make form elements inline 100% width with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to inline elements inside of **div class="col-xs-6"** (see http://jsfiddle.net/hx1mvjnv/2/ )

```
<form role="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background: yellow">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><label for="dept" class="label label-default">Department</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dept" /></li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default inline" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

My goal is to make them 100% width (no free yellow space inside the div). Styling **form** as **from-inline** doesn't help. Is there any ways to do this?

Comment: Do you want the label "document" on the same line too?

Comment: @Dura no, I need it above the textedit

Comment: Sound like you want `btn-block` on the `<button>`

Answer (score 4):

Give this a look:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/LbQtqEj0we)

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background: yellow">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label for="dept" class="label label-default">Department</label> 
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="dept" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default inline" aria-label="Left Align">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Basically, I put a `container-fluid` inside your `col-xs-6`, then did another `col-xs-*` structure for each of the inputs so they would fill you div completely. Remember, 12 columns to a row.

**Note:** Keep in mind the `col-xs-1` and `col-xs-10` elements can be changed to whatever width you'd like, as long as they don't exceed 12.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I need the label to be above the textbox. I modified your example here http://www.bootply.com/9ZJJYYdD6a but I still can't manage to align right glyphicon button to bottom (same line as textbox)

Comment: Yeah, I see that. The button isn't set to align vertically to the center of the div, and I don't know of a way Bootstrap handles that, so you may need to use some custom cs for that one. Maybe give the container an ID and `"style: vertical-align:center"` it? I'm not too sure about base CSS though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version that will align the search button with text box. 
      http://www.bootply.com/MG8F1B1J2X

Answer (score 0):

In [Bootstrap 4.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/), the "w-100" class does the trick for me.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Left Button</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Right Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I end up wrapping all content with table: http://www.bootply.com/RDvzufjN6A

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="background: yellow;">
        <table><tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <label class="label label-default" for="dept">Department</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="dept" type="text">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 1%; vertical-align: bottom;">
                <button class="btn btn-default inline" aria-label="Left Align" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr></tbody></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This will work for you but I think there are better ways without tables. Good Luck!